# How can I make sure I received whole file through socket stream?

Tags: java, sockets, networking

Ok, So I'm making a Java program that has a server and client and I'm sending a Zip file from server to client. I have sending the file down, almost. But recieving I've found some inconsistency. My code isn't always getting the full archive. I'm guessing it's terminating before the BufferedReader has the full thing. Here's the code for the client:

```
public void run(String[] args) {
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket("jacob-custom-pc", 4444);
            out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader inRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            int size = 0;
            while(true) {

                if(in.available() > 0) {    

                        byte[] array = new byte[in.available()];
                        in.read(array);
                        System.out.println(array.length);


                        System.out.println("recieved file!");
                        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("out.zip");
                        fileOut.write(array);
                        fileOut.close();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
```

So how can I be sure the full archive is there before it writes the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the sending side write the file size before you start writing the file. On the reading side  Read the file size so you know how many bytes to expect. Then call read until you have gotten everything you expect.  With network sockets it may take more than one call to read to get everything that was sent.  This is especially true as your data gets larger.

Comment: Why do you need the file size if TCP is a reliable protocol and it says you the endofstream so that you can determine the size yourself (and you do not need it actually)?

Comment: @Val End of stream only works if the socket is closed after the file is written.  It may be good enough for his simple app. In the general case of sending multiple things over one connection you need a different way to do it.

Comment: Perfect, I ended up using this approach. It does a do-while loop until the total bytes read is equal to the total bytes sent ahead. Thanks to main-- and Val too for the help. You guys are a lot better at this than me. :)

Answer (score 0):

HTTP sends a `content-length: x`+\n in bytes. This is elegant, it might throw a TimeoutException if the conn is broken.

Comment: This question isn't about HTTP.

Comment: My answer isn't "Use HTTP", my Answer is: HTTP use a elegant solution for this well known Problem.

Comment: That is, your answer is you say that your answer is a comment rather than the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a TCP socket. The ZIP file is probably larger than the network MTU, so it will be split up into multiple packets and reassembled at the other side. Still, something like this might happen:

- client connects
- server starts sending. The ZIP file is bigger than the MTU and therefore split up into multiple packets.
- client busy-waits in the `while (true)` until it gets the first packets.
- client notices that data has arrived (`in.available() > 0`)
- client reads all available data, writes it to the file and **exits**
- **the last packets arrive**

So as you can see: Unless the client machine is crazily slow and the network is crazily fast and has a huge MTU, your code simply won't receive the entire file **by design**. That's how you built it.

A different approach: Prefix the data with the length.

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("jacob-custom-pc", 4444);
DataInputStream dataReader = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("out.zip");
long size = dataReader.readLong();
long chunks = size / 1024;
int lastChunk = (int)(size - (chunks * 1024));
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
for (long i = 0; i < chunks; i++) {
    dataReader.read(buf);
    out.write(buf);
}
dataReader.read(buf, 0, lastChunk);
out.write(buf, 0, lastChunk);
```

And the server uses `DataOutputStream` to send the size of the file before the actual file. I didn't test this, but it should work.

Comment: What is MTU. TCP means that there is a connection. Do you mean that connection is closed by timeout and this is reported as if sender has closed the socket smoothely?

Comment: There is no timeout, you simply designed your code to stop receiving data after the first pieces have arrived.

Comment: Also, please don't get me wrong, I don't want to insult you, but developing network code is a bad idea if you have no clue how the stuff you are dealing with works and therefore no idea what you are doing.

Comment: It is good to understand what is TCP/IP but I think that Java API is enough here. You read until `size = read(buf)` returns size = -1. That is the end of stream. No need to overcomplicate the things.

Comment: You see, Unix might be important when you do Java streams. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18767684/1083704. Should I study Unix streams for doing Java I/O?

Comment: So you're suggesting I send the size and bytes at the same time? Wouldn't the datareader try to read the whole thing (size and bytes) at the same time?

Comment: @Jadar You are using TCP: You aren't sending size and contents *at the same time*, you are **first** sending the size and **then**, *after that*, the file's contents.

Comment: i meant same time as writing to the buffer and then flushing so it would seem they both go at the same time. guess I don't fully understand TCP yet.

Comment: @Main-- would this be a good way of doing it as to keep the socket open still? or would you still recommend chunking? http://pastebin.com/Bd8uAsrx

Comment: also, im confused on how yours works. it has the buffer but its only 1024 bytes large, and it looks like you're just putting the next values written on top of that, like a stack. so wouldn't it fill up if the file was bigger than 1 kb? and why does it read one more time after the loop?

Comment: @Jadar Imagine you're sending a big backup archive that is 500 GB big. What would the new code you posted do? Exactly: It would try to allocate 500 GB **in RAM** and the probably fail because you don't have that much RAM. My code only moves 1 KB at a time, thus dramatically reducing the required resources.

Comment: @Jadar In that for loop, I always first read 1 KB and the write that into the file. I do that until the next block would be the last block. Then I calculate remaining bytes and transfer those. I have to do that because not every file's size is a multiple of the buffer size.

Comment: It is not a stack. Stream = FIFO.

Comment: Ahh i see. That makes sense. What are you saying Val?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make sure I received whole file through socket stream?

By fixing your code. You are using `InputStream.available()` as a test for end of stream. That's not what it's for. Change your copy loop to this, which is also a whole lot simpler:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Use with any buffer size greater than zero, typically 8192.

Answer (score -1):

`In.available()` just tells you that there is no data to be consumed by `in.read()` without blocking (waiting) at the moment but it does not mean the end of stream. But, they may arrive into your PC at any time, with TCP/IP packet. Normally, you never use `in.available()`. `In.read()` suffices everything for the reading the stream entirely. The pattern for reading the input streams is

```
byte[] buf;
int size;

while ((size = in.read(buf)) != -1)
  process(buf, size);

// end of stream has reached
```

This way you will read the stream entirely, until its end.

**update** If you want to read multiple files, then chunk you stream into "packets" and prefix every one with an integer size. You then read until size bytes is received instead of `in.read = -1`.

**update2** Anyway, never use `in.available` for demarking between the chunks of data. If you do that, you imply that there is a time delay between incoming data pieces. You can do this only in the real-time systems. But Windows, Java and TCP/IP are all these layers incompatible with real-time.

Comment: What if it thinks the stream is done but there are more incoming bytes?

Comment: @Jadar End of stream means the socket is closed, so there won't be more incoming bytes.  The only real drawback is the client can't tell the difference between success and error because of connection loss.

Comment: what if i want to keep the socket open for more transfers?

Comment: Then you chunk the tarnsfers, just like any packet sender does: you prefix the chunk of data with the length and rely on it rather than `available` or `read()=-1`. In this case, if `read = -1` but you expect more, you throw unexpected `EOFException`, as http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readBoolean%28%29 does

Comment: That should be `process(buf, 0, size);`.

Comment: Why not `process(buf, 100 mln, size)`?

Comment: Because it's wrong. It doesn't even make sense. ***What on earth*** do you mean by `100 mln?`

Comment: Zero is not an 'arbitrary number': it is the only correct value here. Conversely, `100 mln` isn't a number at all, it is just invalid syntax. If you don't understand the requirement to use the read count, you shouldn't be answering the question. Answers to questions here are supposed to be 'perfect', i.e. correct: otherwise they attract adverse comment and downvotes.

Comment: You confuse the process function with InputStream.read(). The process is not even a function. It is a placehodler for user code. It accepts semantics and you are not forced to use 0 at all anywhere. I do not understand why do you claim that I do not understand the importance of size, after I fixed my answer. You seem to find all sorts of reasons to avoid answering why best answer needs 0. I like that you pursue the SO policy for perfect answers. Can you remind it there http://superuser.com/questions/644690/why-is-hibernation-still-used/644754?noredirect=1#comment808420_644780?